Why is only one of my proxy facets showing up on etherscan contract verification?
I deployed a diamond upgradeable contract on Sepolia with foundry --verify:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xdCfB65CC9f69D78dDFA30f47eefD1594466fB47D
Only one of my facets shows up, but several others do not.  I verified that it is a proxy contract on etherscan, and in the transactions several functions have been run from other facets.
Here is one of the facets that was deployed at the same time, but those functions are not available when I try to read/write as proxy:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x89c0c798F3bd452f75bCD384e53d755575145C0c#code
I have successfully called them, so I know the facet is working.  Am I still able to add these facets?  Or did I do something wrong in the initial verification process?

Did you tried to ask the problem to the Etherscan team ?

I didn't even know I could.
